# evaluating this difficult integral

Tags: calculus

I have to evaluate this integral:
$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{x}_{-\infty}xe^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}dydx$

I know how to evaluate the next integral:
$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$

But I just cant figure out how to do first one. I need hints.

Comment: @Argon do you mean like: $x^2+y^2=r$ and $dydx=rd\phi dr$? I did try, but there is also an $x$ there.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of integration?

Comment: This looks like substitution of $e^{something}$

Comment: @MichaelBiro I also wanted to do that, but I was confused how to change it. I dont know the 'rules' exactly'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interchange the order of the variables:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^x x e^{-x^2} e^{-y^2}\ dy\ dx
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2} \int_{y}^\infty x e^{-x^2}\ dx\ dy $$

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate by parts:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-x^2} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-y^2} dy\right) dx
&=& -\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-y^2} dy\right)d(e^{-x^2}) \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}d\left(\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-y^2} dy\right) \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\left(e^{-x^2}dx\right) \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2x^2}dx \\ &=&\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-x^2} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-y^2}\, dy \, dx =
 \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-x^2} \left[\operatorname{erf}x \right]_{-\infty}^x \, dx =
 \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\operatorname{erf} x+1)x e^{-x^2} \, dx =
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt 2}$$

and the last integral can be done by parts, because $\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{erf} x = \frac{2e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

Comment: I cant follow this one, a little too fast.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Change the order of integration. It turns into two known integrals.